# Google App Engine KeyProperty

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask, app-engine-ndb

what's the benefits of KeyProperty ? if i can connect  two entity using user_id and id

```
   class User(ndb.Model):

        name = ndb.StringProperty()

   class Attend(ndb.Model):
        user_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
        date = ndb.DateProperty()

User(id=1,name="xyz)
Attend(user_id = 1, date = "xyz")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of minor benefits of storing a `KeyProperty` over an ID:

- It is easier to do x.user_key.get() than ndb.Key(Attend, x.user_id).get()
- The key is fully specified so there is no doubt about the entity it refers to but for the ID you also need to know the entity type.

These are both really minor so you can do either one.  I sometimes store keys and sometimes store IDs based on other factors.

Comment: At 2nd bullet the parent key, if applicable, also needs to be known